# Webpack multiple config files with dependencies

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I have two config files I'd like to compile together using webpack. I found out that if I have two config files imported as `clientConfig` and `serverConfig`, and I pass them within an array to the `webpack([clientConfig, serverConfig]).run(...` call, they'll get both bundled.

However I now have a dependency where the `serverConfig` compilation needs a files generated by the `clientConfig` compilation. I have set `clientConfig` first in the array expecting webpack to first handle `clientConfig` and then `serverConfig`, but it seems not to be happening, since `serverConfig` compilation complains about the missing file, even though when checking in the output folder, it exists after the error.

Is there any way to tell webpack to wait for the first compilation before starting the next one, without having to split this in two `webpack().run...` calls?

Thanks!

Comment: So, running two `webpack()` is working ? It could be that the file from `clientConfig` is not written to disk as long as the webpack process is running... Really not sure about the issue here.

Comment: Yes @ChrisR, two separate webpack calls are working.